# Еще об интернет-терминах. "Гуглить"

Tags: терминология

В обсуждении троллинга (кстати, слава Богу, что тролли пока не завелись на нашем форуме!) коснулись слова "гуглить". Если честно, мне оно кажется словом-уродом. Может, его даже придумали специально для пиара Гугла. В конце концов, люди пользуются далеко не только Гуглом, да и почему не сказать просто "искать"?

Answer (score 1):

Искать можно носки, ключи, деньги, любовь и т.д. А "гуглить" сужает это понятие до поиска в интернете. Как уже было сказано в упоминаемой вами теме, это слово стало нарицательным, как и ксерокс, как и памперс. Так что пришло это слово не для пиара, а ввиду популярности данного поисковика. Сейчас иногда даже можно услышать: "айфон от Самсунга". Подразумевается, конечно, сенсорный телефон, но индивидуумы, которые так говорят, этого не понимают.
Лично я считаю это слово обычным неологизмом, который из-за своего удобного произношения мерным шагом вошел в повседневный лексикон.

Answer (score -1):

Странно, я вроде сюда писал... Рискну хотя бы тезисно повторить, ибо просто нет причин усмотреть в невиннейшем посте что-то криминальное.
~1. Я не считаю "гуглить" чем-то вопиющим. Жаргонизм, коим числа несть.
~2. Гуглить для меня это использовать именно гугл. В прочих случаях можно услышать аналогичные образования от названий других поисковиков.

Comment: У меня просьба к минусящим - давайте хоть знать, что именно не понравилось. Аргументированную критику воспринимаю с благодарностью.
В данном случае не могу даже предположить, чем и кого могло так задеть моё личное мнение.

Comment: А мы не начинаем снова повторять недавнее обсуждение? См. здесь ["Гуглить с помощью Яндекса"][1]

(**behemothus**, я не минусовал, если что)



  [1]: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/8554/иностранные-слова-гуглить-с-помощью-яндекса

Comment: Да, похоже на то. Видимо это меня и сбило, когда я решил, что уже отвечал тут. Спасибо, Nikolja.